# Text Grouping Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, coffeescript, dynamic-programming

Given an arbitrary string of text, the task is to group the text into separate sections of a template. Each section has different min length and max length parameters. A solution can be considered optimal for a section as long as it falls within those bounds. A greedy solution might result in some sections not meeting their minimums, which means the solution as a whole is not acceptable.

I'm having trouble efficiently constructing an algorithm to do this. It seems that a dynamic programming approach might help, but thus far, I haven't been able to couch it in dynamic programming terms. Does anyone have any leads on solving this problem?

```
function groupText(str, template)
Inputs:
 str: a string of text
 template: array of JavaScript objects. 
           One object per section that describes the min/max amount of text allowed
Output:
 array: each element corresponds to one section. 
        The value of the element is the text that is in the section.
```

As an example, let's define a string str that is equal to "This is a test." We also have a template *t*. *t* consists of several sections. Each section *s* has a minimum and maximum amount of characters allowed. Let's say for this example there are only two sections: *s1* and *s2*. *s1* has a minimum of 1 character and a maximum of 100. *s2* has a minimum of 10 characters and a maximum of 15. We pass our string *str* and our template *t* to a function *groupText*. *groupText* must return an array, with each element *i* corresponding to a section. For example, element 0 will correspond to *s1*. The value of the element will be the text that has been assigned to the section.

In this example, a solution might be.

*s1text* = "This "

*s2text* = "is a test."

Comment: An example of what you want to do would help us understand your question much better.  Especially an example of the input and desired output.

Comment: This sounds like a linear programming problem.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I've added an example. Let me know if that helps. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: That's not an example, it's a sort-of-pseudocode restatement of your original question.

Comment: @mdkess - Thanks for the tip. I don't have much familiarity with linear programming, but I'll get out my copy of CLRS and see what I can find.

Comment: @tabdulla: The basic format is "Find x1, x2, x3, ..., xn >= 0 such that x1 + min1 <= max1, and x2 + min2 <= max2, ...". It's been a while though, so I might be wrong about my hunch.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry about that. Added a real example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly there's no need of any search... just subtract from the total length the sum of the minimum lengths and what remains is the amount to be distributed. Then distribute this amount to each element up to its maximum until nothing is left... in code

```
var minsum = 0;
for (vsr i=0; i < sections.length; i++)
    minsum += sections[i].min_size;
var extra = text.length - minsum;
if (extra < 0) return null; // no solution
var solution = [];
for (var i=0; i < sections.length; i++)
{
    var x = sections[i].min_size + extra;
    if (x > sections[i].max_size)
        x = sections[i].max_size;
    solution.push(x);
    extra -= x - sections[i].min_size;
}
if (extra > 0) return null; // no solution
return solution;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's an ad-hoc, untested algorithm.  If it's no good, perhaps it's good enough to goad someone else into a better answer;

Let's have some trial data.  Suppose your template comprises 6 sections, which have min,max limits as:

```
1 - 12
13 - 25
5 - 7
6 - 7
5 - 5
10 - 25
```

which means that you're going to need a string of at least 40 and at most 81 characters to satisfy your constraints.  And therein lies the solution.  First, compute a table like this:

```
40 - 81
39 - 69
26 - 34
21 - 37
15 - 30
10 - 25
```

in which each row gives the total length of string that can still be partitioned across the 'slots' in your template.  Into slot 1 you put text so that you still have between 39 and 69 characters left for the rest of the slots.  Into slot 2 you put text so that you still have between 26 and 34 characters.  And so on.